# What is the lambda in this foldr doing?

Tags: haskell

I'm working my way through the [Haskell book](http://haskellbook.com/) and I'm a bit stumped understanding folds. One exercise asks the reader to write an `elem` function with `foldr`. I couldn't get my head round it and googled an example, which I'm now trying to understand. The type signature for `foldr` is:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

The example function I found is:

```
myElem' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool 
myElem' a = foldr (\x y -> a == x || y) False
```

My understanding is that `(\x y -> a == x || y)` is fulfilling the `(a -> b -> b)` part of the type, `False` is fulfilling the `b` and `t a` is being implied in point free style.

But the lambda itself seems like magic just now. I'm reading it as a function x with one parameter y will check if `x(y) == a`, with a being the element supplied as an argument to `myElem'`, and return True or the original argument to `x`. That's clearly nonsense. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Lambdas are anonymous. `x` is not the name of the function, but one of the arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\x y -> a == x || y` is a function with two parameters, named `x` and `y`. It returns `True` whenever `a == x` is `True` or `y` is `True`.

Comment: maybe it is a bit easier to see with explicit parenthization `\x y -> (a == x) || y`

Comment: Okay, so is the `y` just the accumulated value of the fold and `x` the head of the structure being folded?

Comment: @GarryCairns You got it.

Comment: @GarryCairns You could look at it that way, but it's kind of a trap to think of `foldr` as using an accumulator, at least in Haskell.  The value `y` represents the result of the rest of the fold - but suspended.  It's never actually evaluated unless it's needed.  That's a huge part of why `foldr` is actually useful in Haskell.